# Azure Redis Exception while executing function: MyFunction -> Unable to find assembly 'MySolution.MyProject.MyService

Tags: c#, .net, azure, stackexchange.redis, cachingframework.redis

While using CachingFramework.Redis I am trying to insert an object into a key, field hash...

```
enter code here
var map = new MyMapping
{
   DataSourceId = source.DataSourceId,
   ExternalId = source.ExternalId,
   StoreId = source.StoreId ?? 0,
   LastConnection = source.LastConnection,
   ApiKey = source.ApiKey
};
Context.Cache.SetHashed("MyRedisKey", "MyFieldKey", map, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

But, when I try to get the hashed value back out...

```
var MyCachedValue = Context.Cache.GetHashed<MyMapping>(("MyRedisKey", "MyFieldKey");
```

I get the error...

> "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: MyFunction ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Unable to find assembly 'MySolution.MyProject.MyService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.FunctionInvocationFilterInvoker.InvokeAsync(Object instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)\r\n ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting and retrieving the value in different assemblies? It looks like that might be the case.

In that event, you need your `Map` to be defined in a shared assembly that is referenced by both the project that sets the value as well as the project that gets the value.

1. GetterProject
2. SetterProject
3. SharedModels

Both 1 and 2 should reference 3, and that is where you should define the objects stored in your cache.

Comment: Yup, that did it! That was exactly what was happening, thank you.